# How to find which part of the apps inserting blank data into a table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm

I am having this problem. One table in our application database keeps getting blank data inserted. It is a master table, so normally no new data is added. Now, I want to know where that insert operations come from. I cannot find any reference in my source code where we can insert data to this particular table.

So, I create a trigger so that whenever the table get insert operation, it will fail. Hopefully, I can catch whatever is creating the insertions.

Yesterday I see the following in our log:

```
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
        : ER_CANT_UPDATE_USED_TABLE_IN_SF_OR_TRG: Can't update table 'provinces' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which inv
        oked this stored function/trigger.
            at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:48:14)
            at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:83:18)
            at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
            at Parser.write (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:73:12)
            at Protocol.write (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:96:28)
            at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
            at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
            at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
            at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
            at TCP.onread (net.js:559:20)
            --------------------
            at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
            at PoolConnection.query (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:201:25)
            at Object.f.dynatraceRegularInvoke [as doInvoke] (/opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/res/nodeagent/nodejsagent.js:9243:20)
            at Object.a.safeInvoke (/opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/res/nodeagent/nodejsagent.js:9316:29)
            at PoolConnection.query (/opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/res/nodeagent/nodejsagent.js:6104:15)
            at __CREATE__ (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:394:20)
            at afterwards (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:84:5)
            at /home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:40:7
            at Ping.onOperationComplete [as _callback] (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:99:5)
            at Ping.Sequence.end (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
            at Ping.Sequence.OkPacket (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:105:8)
            at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
            at Parser.write (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:73:12)
            at Protocol.write (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/apps/brambang/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:96:28)
            at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
            at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
            at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
            at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
            at TCP.onread (net.js:559:20)

Details:  Error: ER_CANT_UPDATE_USED_TABLE_IN_SF_OR_TRG: Can't update table 'provinces' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Okay, now I know that one part of this app is inserting something to the table, now the question is how do I identify which part of my apps is doing this?

Any idea how I should proceed with this? I found no reference to which part of the code is doing this.

Thank you.

- I have put Not Null check on the table, but blank data keeps coming in (before the trigger created), not a null, but blank.
- I even created a scheduler to delete anything with id > 94, because with blank data exist in the table, there are parts of the web apps getting errors.
- I want to get to the bottom of this, what is creating those blank data.